# Can a person who undergo samadhi state once loose his power of going to samadhi?

Tags: yoga, samadhi

Consider a person who undergoes the samadhi state once.

Is there a possibility that the person loses the power to reach the samadhi state after that?

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no such possibility. Samadhi leads to moksha and moksha is not subject to the destructive force of time. Inability to attain samadhi would imply non-attainment of moksha. That would suggest that the person did not attain Samadhi in the first place.

> One who aspires to overcome the thick darkness of ignorance should
> never seek contacts that are contrary to the fourfold end of life
> (Dharma, Artha, Kama and Moksha). Of these four ends, **Moksha alone
> is accepted as the really stable value to be sought**; for the other
> three are subject to the destructive force of Time.

**Srimad Bhagavata Purana IV.22.34-35**

Comment: Yeah, I also didn't encounter any yogi doing sins after reaching the samadhi state.

Comment: A yogi who does sins after the samadhi state will experience the closing of the cakras. It will be a terrible experience. Of course he will not commit any sin.